# M2E turn off resolve workspace dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have eclipse oxygen with M2E installed. I usually update my dependencies via Right Click -> Spring Tools -> Update Maven Dependencies. This uses `Resolve Workspace Dependencies` by default which I don't want.

How can I turn that option off by default?

---

For now I have to use command line with the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` which one should not be using anymore

Note: My projects are **not** maven projects within eclipse

Comment: As a footnote, I'd like to ask, why do you want to disable this ?

Comment: @deztructicus because other developer update only the dependency, but not the files within TFS and therefore I have older versions than what I need

Answer (score 0):

If you right click and go to Maven -> Update Maven Project you should be brought to a window. At this window there will be an option to select the code bases to update as well as not forcing update of snapshots or releases. This should help you get around this.

EDIT: The question has been edited to point out the projects are not maven projects in eclipse. This answer is less relevant

Comment: For that I have to convert the projects to maven projects and this causes a few compiler errors